# pandas groupby datetime.date object is not consistent

Tags: python, pandas

For example

```
import datetime
data={'date':[datetime.date(2020,1,i) for i in range(11,13)],
     'a1':range(11,13),
     'a2':range(21,23)}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If we groupby only the date column, everything is ok

```
g=df.groupby('date')
print(g.groups)
g.get_group(list(g.groups.keys())[0])
```

gives

```
{datetime.date(2020, 1, 11): Int64Index([0], dtype='int64'), datetime.date(2020, 1, 12): Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')}

    date    a1  a2
0   2020-01-11  11  21
```

However, if we groupby two column to form multiIndex, we got problem

```
g=df.groupby(['date','a1'])
print(g.groups)
g.get_group(list(g.groups.keys())[0])
```

gives

```
{(Timestamp('2020-01-11 00:00:00'), 11): Int64Index([0], dtype='int64'), (Timestamp('2020-01-12 00:00:00'), 12): Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')}
```

and error message

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 g=df.groupby(['date','a1'])
>         2 print(g.groups)
>   ----> 3 g.get_group(list(g.groups.keys())[0])
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py
>   in get_group(self, name, obj)
>       678         inds = self._get_index(name)
>       679         if not len(inds):
>   --> 680             raise KeyError(name)
>       681 
>       682         return obj.take(inds, axis=self.axis)
>
> KeyError: (Timestamp('2020-01-11 00:00:00'), 11)

We can see pandas `groupby` is too smart to change `datetime.date` object to `Timestamp` object. And it mess up indexing, we can not get the correct group. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can try grouping like this:

```
g=df.groupby([['date','a1']])
print(g.groups)
g.get_group(list(g.groups.keys())[0])
```